# asp.net mvc template missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, development-environment

I installed asp.net mvc and then followed it up by installation of visual studio 2008 express. When I do new project I dont see mvc template to choose from.
How do i add the asp.net mvc template for visual studio to know where it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a repair of your asp.net mvc package or try to reinstall it.

Comment: its a fresh installation, i just need to make some configiration changes in visual studio so that it is pointed to mvc , dont know which one though

Comment: You installed both products in the wrong order. That's why you need to reinstall mvc. The installation package probably didn't detect any version of Visual Studio and skipped installing the templates.

Comment: did same, uninstalled mvc and then installed again, VS Studio found it this time, though would like to know magic behind scene

Comment: I had the same issue. I uninstalled MVC and VWD and then used the Web Platform Installer to reinstall them both.

Answer (score 0):

I think VS 2008 Express is missing the template by default.

"**Note**   Web application projects do not work with Visual Web Developer Express Edition."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem and then I realized that target framework in new project dialog was 2.0
Also, you can get asp.net mvc only from 'new project' dialog, not from 'new website'

cheers